# data source with local report an custom objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting, rdlc

i'm trying to add a datasource to my local report. the data source is a custom object like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    Person[] GetData();
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Person[] GetData()
    {
        return new Person[1] { new Person { Name = "Foo" } };
    }
}
```

Now if i try to add a data source the only choice is the database data source. Why?

How can i add a data source with my custom objects. I want add this data source to the designer, because of i want to design my report in visual studio.

[image: Visual Studio]

If i put the report in a separate project and add a reference to data source dll then the option for object data source is visible. Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

- Visual Studio 2010 SP 1
- ASP.NET MVC 3
- Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this ?